# Python Pandas: recoding a variable's levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a categorical variable in a pandas dataframe, `varA`. It has 4 levels: [1, 3, 1.0, 3.0] instead of just [1, 3]. I'm struggling to map 1.0 to 1. Example data set:

```
df[['varA', 'ID']].groupby(['varA']).count()

         count
varA    
1        100
1.0      10
3        300
3.0      30
```

What I tried:

`df[['varA']].replace(1.0, 1)`

But nothing changed. I'm sure this is a simple and trivial issue but I've been unable to resolve it. I am expecting:

```
         count
varA    
1        110
3        330
```

Comment: Why don't you set its type to `int` then. `df['varA'].astype(int)`

Comment: @Alexander your code and Anurag's returns this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'`

Comment: `df['varA'] = df['varA'].astype(float).astype(int)`

Comment: @sammywemmy I tried: `df['varA'].rename_categories({'1.0': '1', '3.0': '3'})` and got: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rename_categories'`

Comment: @Alexander yes that did the trick. thanks.

Comment: sorry. I shared the wrong suggestion. But you have found a solution; so all is good.

Comment: @user2205916 try: ```df['varA'].cat.rename_categories``` (notice the **cat** keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in column `varA` is either text or a mixture of text, floats and integers. You can first try to convert the values to floats, and then convert the result to integers:

```
df['varA'] = df['varA'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `downcast` param of `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df['varA'] = pd.to_numeric(df['varA'], downcast='integer')
```

---

```
         count
varA    
1        100
1.0      10
3        300
3.0      30
```

Note: If `varA` is your index (as it looks like), you can access it via `df.index` instead of `df['varA']`.